# MvcMailer Send() extension method missing in ASP.Net MVC 4 

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, mvcmailer

After upgrading one of my websites to MVC 4 and upgrade all my packages in NuGet I seem to have lost the Send() extension method for the MvcMailer package from NuGet. I have not made any code changes other then those necessary to upgrade the project and I have:

```
using Mvc.Mailer;
```

At the top of my code file.

Can someone please tell me what may be going on here?

Comment: Did you try to clean up your solution? (right click on solution->Clean Solution)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I figured it out after looking at this post:
https://github.com/smsohan/MvcMailer/issues/68

Basically they have removed the extension method from `MailMessage` and added a new class called `MvcMailMessage` which your mailer should return instead.